# Set a bones matrix to a custom matrix

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, bones

I have a script in which I compute a custom matrix for each bone of a skeleton. I know I have switch to edit mode but then I read that the property `edit_bone.matrix` is read-only for bones. Now, because I know how matrices work, I thought, I would just set the bones matrix to Identity() (`edit_bone.head` to `(0, 0, 0)` and `edit_bone.tail` to `(0, 1, 0)`). But when I then do transform the bone the outcome is not what I expected. The script-snippet is the following:

```
for bone in self._data.edit_bones:
    ebone = armature.edit_bones.new(bone.name)
    # ebone.head = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) # already default
    ebone.tail = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    t_matrix = Matrix(bone.transform) # use blender-intern Matrix
    # the following call should set ebone.matrix to t_matrix
    # cannot do that directly, is currently wrong
    ebone.transform(t_matrix)
    print(t_matrix, ebone.matrix, sep='\n')
```

This gives the following output:

```
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.9665, -0.2564, -0.0119, 17.7405)
            ( 0.0171, -0.0183, -0.9997,  0.0280)
            ( 0.2561, -0.9664,  0.0221, -0.0120)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.0530, -0.0119,  0.9985, 17.7405)
            ( 0.0227, -0.9997, -0.0107,  0.0280)
            ( 0.9983,  0.0221,  0.0533, -0.0120)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
```

Notice how the translation is correct but I don't understand why the other part isn't. Can anyone give an insight what is going on and provide a solution to my problem?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but doesn't the standard bone point in the z-direction? In my oppinion the tail should be set to (0,0,1).

Comment: I checked and no, (0, 1, 0) gives `bone.matrix == Matrix.Identity(4)`

Comment: `.matrix` can't be set, you need to set `.roll` and the both endpoints instead. There are 2 utility function: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.EditBone.html?highlight=align_#bpy.types.EditBone.align_roll

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more? Is there a method to calculate the Eigen-vector of a matrix or do I have to write that on my own? Feel free to post a full answer.

Comment: I don't know anything about Eigen-vectors, but aren't the available methods sufficient? There's also [EditBone.transform()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.EditBone.html?highlight=transform#bpy.types.EditBone.transform) and [Object.convert_space()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=convert_space#bpy.types.Object.convert_space).

Comment: you clearly didn't read the question. It says that EditBone.transform() doesn't work, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`bone.transform()` also didn't work very well for me, so I used a method I found in a blenderartists post to extract the roll and tail from a matrix:

```
def vec_roll_to_mat3(vec, roll):
    target = Vector((0, 0.1, 0))
    nor = vec.normalized()
    axis = target.cross(nor)
    if axis.dot(axis) > 0.0000000001: # this seems to be the problem for some bones, no idea how to fix
        axis.normalize()
        theta = target.angle(nor)
        bMatrix = Matrix.Rotation(theta, 3, axis)
    else:
        updown = 1 if target.dot(nor) > 0 else -1
        bMatrix = Matrix.Scale(updown, 3)

        # C code:
        #bMatrix[0][0]=updown; bMatrix[1][0]=0.0;    bMatrix[2][0]=0.0;
        #bMatrix[0][1]=0.0;    bMatrix[1][1]=updown; bMatrix[2][1]=0.0;
        #bMatrix[0][2]=0.0;    bMatrix[1][2]=0.0;    bMatrix[2][2]=1.0;
        bMatrix[2][2] = 1.0

    rMatrix = Matrix.Rotation(roll, 3, nor)
    mat = rMatrix * bMatrix
    return mat

def mat3_to_vec_roll(mat):
    vec = mat.col[1]
    vecmat = vec_roll_to_mat3(mat.col[1], 0)
    vecmatinv = vecmat.inverted()
    rollmat = vecmatinv * mat
    roll = math.atan2(rollmat[0][2], rollmat[2][2])
    return vec, roll
```

Then, to set it:

```
tail, roll = mat3_to_vec_roll(matrix)
bone.head = matrix.to_translation()
bone.tail = tail*boneLength + bone.head
bone.roll = roll
```

Answer (score 1):

The code found in [Emd4600's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38337/45904) works with most, but not all bones. That code was a port of the [internal C code of blender, which has meanwhile been improved](https://developer.blender.org/T39470). I have ported this newer, improved version into python. I have not extensively tested it, but it seems correct, produces good results and it was super easy to port. It is used in the exact same way as before (see [Emd4600's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38337/45904)), should be more accurate and get all (?) bone orientations right!

```
def vec_roll_to_mat3(vec, roll):
    #port of the updated C function from armature.c
    #https://developer.blender.org/T39470
    #note that C accesses columns first, so all matrix indices are swapped compared to the C version

    nor = vec.normalized()
    THETA_THRESHOLD_NEGY = 1.0e-9
    THETA_THRESHOLD_NEGY_CLOSE = 1.0e-5

    #create a 3x3 matrix
    bMatrix = mathutils.Matrix().to_3x3()

    theta = 1.0 + nor[1];

    if (theta > THETA_THRESHOLD_NEGY_CLOSE) or ((nor[0] or nor[2]) and theta > THETA_THRESHOLD_NEGY):

        bMatrix[1][0] = -nor[0];
        bMatrix[0][1] = nor[0];
        bMatrix[1][1] = nor[1];
        bMatrix[2][1] = nor[2];
        bMatrix[1][2] = -nor[2];
        if theta > THETA_THRESHOLD_NEGY_CLOSE:
            #If nor is far enough from -Y, apply the general case.
            bMatrix[0][0] = 1 - nor[0] * nor[0] / theta;
            bMatrix[2][2] = 1 - nor[2] * nor[2] / theta;
            bMatrix[0][2] = bMatrix[2][0] = -nor[0] * nor[2] / theta;

        else:
            #If nor is too close to -Y, apply the special case.
            theta = nor[0] * nor[0] + nor[2] * nor[2];
            bMatrix[0][0] = (nor[0] + nor[2]) * (nor[0] - nor[2]) / -theta;
            bMatrix[2][2] = -bMatrix[0][0];
            bMatrix[0][2] = bMatrix[2][0] = 2.0 * nor[0] * nor[2] / theta;

    else:
        #If nor is -Y, simple symmetry by Z axis.
        bMatrix = mathutils.Matrix().to_3x3()
        bMatrix[0][0] = bMatrix[1][1] = -1.0;

    #Make Roll matrix
    rMatrix = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(roll, 3, nor)

    #Combine and output result
    mat = rMatrix * bMatrix
    return mat

def mat3_to_vec_roll(mat):
    #this hasn't changed
    vec = mat.col[1]
    vecmat = vec_roll_to_mat3(mat.col[1], 0)
    vecmatinv = vecmat.inverted()
    rollmat = vecmatinv * mat
    roll = math.atan2(rollmat[0][2], rollmat[2][2])
    return vec, roll
```